# Setting connection options for PostgreSQL JDBC connection from Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, datasource

My application was using Mongo DB earlier. Now, I'm shifting to PostgreSQL. For that, I've been migrating queries and all. But, I was being blocked by issue. In MongoDB connection, we've some MongoClientOptions used to improve the performance of the application. In some way, I want to set these options with JDBC for PostgreSQL also.

I've tried and searched the same functions in JDBC DriverManager class. But didn't find any.

MongoDB connection options used are added below,
How can I set these options for JDBC client for PostgreSQL?

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
builder.threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(1000);
builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(60* 1000 * 5);
builder.connectionsPerHost(100000);
MongoClientOptions options = builder.build();
mongoClient = new MongoClient(hostname, options);
```

Comment: I don't know what those options do in MongoDB, but from the names  of it, it looks like you are looking for a connection pool. In which environment does your application run? Web Application? Swing Rich Client? Something else?

Comment: Actually, It's web application backend code.

Comment: Then use the connection pool that comes with your application server (e.g. Tomcat's pool)

Comment: I didn't get that. You're saying I've to Tomcat's pool in place of JDBC driver? please light me on this. I'm new to this web application and all

Comment: The pool will _use_ the JDBC driver to connect to the database: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Thank you. Will look into that page

Answer (score 1):

In JDBC you pass a `Properties` object with some JDBC-standard properties ("user" and "password") and driver-specific properties, or pass the properties as part of the JDBC-url (with driver-specific properties and driver-specific syntax), or you configure things using a `DataSource` and its getters and setters.

For PostgreSQL JDBC refer to the section [Connecting to the Database](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html)

For almost any serious usage of JDBC, you should not use `DriverManager` directly as it will create a new physical connection for each request. Instead use a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation that provides connection pooling, either provided by your driver (those usually aren't very good though), a third-party library like HikariCP, or one built into your JavaEE application server.

Comment: Thanks. But one question. I've been using `DriverManager.getConnection()` function. It will return a Connection object. On that Connection object I've been executing queries. How it's going to use new physical connection for each request?

Comment: @MuhammedThabjeel Each time you call `DriverManager.getConnection`, you'll create a **new** physical connection. And given you should **not share** a connection concurrently, you'll need to call `DriverManager.getConnection` for individual requests, thus you'll be creating a new connection per request (and if you aren't currently doing that, you have even bigger problems with race conditions and other concurrency bugs). The solution is to use a connection pool, as instead of closing physical connections, a `Connection.close()` will return it to the pool for reuse.

Comment: Oh, then that's a big mess. But I've all my CRUD functions(Where I actually use this **singleton** Connection object and making queries) as synchronized. Will that help? And can you please share some links for connection pool?

Comment: @MuhammedThabjeel Individual actions might be safe (but probably not), but larger interactions might still suffer from race conditions (guess what happens when one request rolls back and another one commits, while another one is updating / inserting something that depends on data it inserted earlier). In addition, having a single synchronization bottle neck in your application will make your application unnecessarily slow. For links, Google and DuckDuckGo are your friend. Correctly using a connection pool will make things **simpler** and usually **faster**.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. If I'm using a connection pool, I don't need to synchronize methods, right?

Comment: @MuhammedThabjeel There is no black/white there, it really depends on your code and how/what it is supposed to do, but my first instinct would be no. But it sounds like you are a bit out of your depth with writing scalable thread-safe applications. You might want to ask your colleagues for help.